# CSS how to affect the ::after state when hovering over an element

Tags: css

I have a set CSS properties to an ::after state of an element. How can I change its ::after color when hovering over the "parent" element itself?

```
.nav.navbar-nav .menu-item .nav-link::after{
content: "*";
color:#fff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav .menu-item .nav-link:hover > .nav.navbar-nav .menu-item .nav-link::after{
color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well, and [edit your question to include an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the `:hover` and `::after` to make it work. See the example below.

```css
span::after {
  content: "This is a psuedo element";
}

span:hover::after {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Hover here!</span>
```

Comment: You mention a parent element. Within my example you mean the ```span``` element or more like a second container / element?